# Validating Webhook behaviour

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

Is it possible to restrict `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration` to a single namespace as I am looking to restrict the CR to get deployed in a single namespace only. Is this a feasible requirement to achieve?